# Powershell lowercase tab expansion?

Tags: powershell

Powershell supports typing commands in lowercase. However, powershell's tab completion will camelcase all commands, which I personally find difficult to parse visually. Is there any way to let powershell's tab expansion/completion default to all lowercase instead of camelcase?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to change this preference today, but you can pretty well easily hook into the PowerShell ISE if you like. One thing you could do is grab the text off the editor, split on new-line chars ("`n"), and then iterate over the resulting array to parse out cmdlet names, make them lower-case, and append onto a new script-body. This all sounds fairly complex, but it is actually fairly simple to do. I've got something similar in an alias-resolution add-in I wrote, which can be found at https://github.com/briandrennan/PowerShellISE/blob/Edit/Resolve-ScriptAliases.ps1. Basically, you'd want to create some kind of an index (hash table would work well) that stores commands, and then just call ToLower() on the name, and insert in your script over the previous one. That script has all the bits you need to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: That's sad. I would like to write commands in lower case. I don't care if they are later converted otherwise ;)

Comment: These days, the PowerShell ISE is not the *preferred* scripting environment. Generally speaking, you author code in something like VSCode (which I believe is the "official" editing environment). You can power it however you like.

One note: PowerShell's not converting your script; it has a case-insensitive syntax, ergo, `Get-Help` is the same thing as `GET-HELP`, `get-help`, and `get-HELP`. There's no conversion happening, per se; it simply doesn't care about character casing.